# Prevent Ajax from triggering jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

We got a simple jQuery script on Drupal site that injects a div class with content:

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myHelpText = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    //code starts

//change placeholder text

$('.form-item-quantity').append('<span class="help-block">For orders over 10 call for volume pricing</span>');
$('.help-block').css("flex-basis", "100%"); 

    //code ends

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

The page has Drupal Commerce and various product attribute fields that gets processed by Ajax every time selecting an attribute. And when doing that our script injects same duplicate line each time on Ajax load/update.

How to avoid that? We just want jQuery code work once on page load.

[image]

Comment: Where is the ajax call? You could add logic to check if the element already exists, and if so, don't add it. Without any more info wont be of much help.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine it's Drupal Commerce platform with 100 of modules not sure how  to pull code here.

Comment: `if(!$('.help-block').length) {//append your data}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add the element if it doesn't exist, otherwise do nothing.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myHelpText = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      if (!document.getElementById('help')) { 
         $('.form-item-quantity').append(
            '<span id="help" class="help-block">For orders over 10 call for volume ricing</span>'
         );
         $('.help-block').css("flex-basis", "100%");
      }

     }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Does it mean it still calls it on every Ajax event? It's working tho. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about Drupal, so can't say when/where your function is being called. Although this will still work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that drupal.behaviors fire on page load **and** when ajax returns results. It is designed this way because you may want your code to run again on the ajax results, for example, if you are updating part of the page via ajax and it needs event listeners applied, or a class added.

The `context` variable is the key here.

on first page load, the context will be the whole window, but when ajax returns the result, the context will just be what is returned by the ajax.
Knowing this, you should be using `context` in your jquery selectors.
eg.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myHelpText = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

    //code starts

    //change placeholder text

    $('.form-item-quantity', context).append('<span class="help-block">For orders over 10 call for volume pricing</span>');
    $('.help-block', context).css("flex-basis", "100%"); 

    //code ends

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

For added protection against something processing multiple times, you can use jquery once(), but this is usually not needed if using the context variable in the selector. jQuery once() separate library that must be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use jQuery once? My thought — it's a classic approach. A bunch of examples lives in docs on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)

`$('.form-item-quantity').once('help-appended').append('<span class="help-block">For orders over 10 call for volume pricing</span>');`

And I'm not sure you need to apply styles via js. A css file is a better place for it. And jquery once should be available in your environment. That's it.